# Google Sheets - copying CONCATENATE'd text deletes line breaks (comes out as massive block)

Tags: google-sheets, text

Issue with Google Sheets:

I have the CONCATENATE function combining text from several cells into 1 "copypastable" block.
I'm inserting line breaks using CHAR(10).

[image]

So it looks fine in Google Sheets itself, and functions perfectly when copied to other Google apps.

But copying it out to other programs (CorelDRAW, Illustrator, or AutoCAD) causes 2 issues:

1.) Adds unwanted double quotes around the entire text.
2.) Destroys all line breaks.

[image]

So I have to manually edit every text block, to delete the quotes and add line breaks.
Huge waste of time. How can I make it work properly?

Interestingly enough, it works more properly in Notepad:

[image]

Still adds the double quotes, but at least the line breaks work.

But having to copy/paste everything into Notepad, deleting the double-quotes, and then copy/pasting it into Corel/Illustrator/AutoCAD - STILL has the issue with the deleted line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the program you're bringing this into, you might want to try using `CHAR(13)` instead of `CHAR(10)`.

`CHAR(13)` is a carriage return, while `CHAR(10)` is a linefeed which will not "show" in google sheets, but when you copy/paste it to a different program depending on the interpretation of those characters it should show up as a separate line.

Answer (score 1):

this is a known issue and one way how to counter it is to copy the content of fx bar (or active cell) instead of the cell itself. you may also want to move down the output to not catch the formula itself. try:

```
={""; CONCATENATE(...)}
```

where `...` is your formula

Comment: @TomJones999 Simplify your formula to this. `={"";TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,P17:T17)}`